# How to get listed of all product

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am looking for solution to display all products on custom cms page or need root category url link on which in can get all product.

I tried with catalog product list widget having product for category id 2 which is root catetory but didn't get success. I am working on magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I got solution, Hope it helps to others.

Use   "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"  class and add below content in any cms page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="category_id" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" name="allproducts"}}
```

Here category_id is ID of Category.